# Create a dynamic admin site

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to create a dynamic admin site, that based on if the field is blank or not will show that field.  So I have a model that has a set number of fields, but for each individual entry will not contain all of the fields in my model and I want to exclude based on if that field is blank.

I  have a unique bridge identifier, that correlates to each bridge, and then all of the various different variables that describe the bridge.

I have it set up now that the user will go to a url with the unique bridgekey and then this will create an entry of that bridge.  So (as i am testing on my local machine) it would be like localhost/home/*brkey* and that code in my views.py that corresponds to that url is

However, not every bridge is the same and I have a lot more variables that I would like to include in my model but for now I am just testing on two : prestressed_concrete_deck and reinforced_concrete_coated_bars.  What I want is to dynamically create the admin site to not display the prestressed_concrete_deck variable if that field is blank.  So instead of displaying all of the variables on the admin site, I want to only display those variables if that bridge has that part, and to not display anything if the field is blank.

Another possible solution to the problem would be to get that unique identifier over to my admins.py.  I cant figure out either how to get that individual key over as then I could query in the admins.py.  If i knew how to access the bridgekey, I could just query in my admins.py dynamically.  So how would I access the brkey for that entry in my admins.py (Something like BridgeModel.brkey ?)

I have tried several different things in my admin.py and have tried the comments suggestion of overwriting the get_fields() method in my admin class, but I am probably syntactically wrong and I am kind of confused what the object it takes exactly is.  Is that the actual entry?  Or is that the individual field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Django 1.6 which did not support overriding the get_fields method.  Updated to 1.7 and this method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the [get_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) method in your ModelAdmin class.

You can check the `obj` is passed as function argument so you can check which fields are empty. The function needs to return a tuple so, you would check if `field1 is None` and then return `(field1, field2, field3)` or `(field2, field3)` depending on the value of `field1`.

Comment: I tried that but I might have been syntactically incorrect, (I tried the code above, and it compiled and ran, but did not hide the field if it was blank).  Do you have any other suggesstions